# ST_Touches function in Spatialite

Tags: spatialite

I'm a newbie to Spatialite so forgive me if the answer to my question is obvious...(I tried looking online but couldn't find the answer to this question).
I am trying to use the function ST_touches in Spatialite Gui but it says it does not recognize that function. Is there anything I need to install in order to use this function? And how?
Thanks so much,
Ana

Comment: Do you have a very old version of spatialite? Can you try with just "Touches" (i.e. leave off the "ST_" part)? If that doesn't work, can you show exactly how you are using the function?

Comment: Was your version compiled with GEOS support?

Answer (score 2):

If you have ST_Touches function in your spatialite-gui the following query will return "1".

```
SELECT ST_Touches(GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))"), GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 1, 0 2, 1 2, 2 1, 0 1))"));
```

If the error message tells that function is missing, believe it. Spatialite-gui 1.7.1 Windows build from the Spatialite site for sure has the function.